# In the program to create a simple websocket, where is the onOpen method being called?

Tags: java, websocket

I found a code to create a simple websocket connection. 
In the main function only the constructor to `WebsocketClientEndpoint` is being called and I don't see a call to `onOpen` function inside the constructor. In the output, "**opening websocket**" is printed as specified in the `onOpen` function. Can anyone please tell me where is the call to the `onOpen` function happening?

TestApp.java:

```
package testapp;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class TestApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // open websocket
        final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI("wss://real.okcoin.cn:10440/websocket/okcoinapi"));

        // add listener
        clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(new WebsocketClientEndpoint.MessageHandler() {
            public void handleMessage(String message) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        });

        // send message to websocket
        clientEndPoint.sendMessage("{'event':'addChannel','channel':'ok_btccny_ticker'}");

        // wait 5 seconds for messages from websocket
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println("InterruptedException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

WebsocketClientEndpoint.java

```
package testapp;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

 /**
 * ChatServer Client
 *
 * @author Jiji_Sasidharan
 */
@ClientEndpoint
public class WebsocketClientEndpoint {

Session userSession = null;
private MessageHandler messageHandler;

public WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI) {
    try {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback hook for Connection open events.
 *
 * @param userSession the userSession which is opened.
 */
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
    System.out.println("opening websocket");
    this.userSession = userSession;
}

/**
 * Callback hook for Connection close events.
 *
 * @param userSession the userSession which is getting closed.
 * @param reason the reason for connection close
 */
@OnClose
public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
    System.out.println("closing websocket");
    this.userSession = null;
}

/**
 * Callback hook for Message Events. This method will be invoked when a client send a message.
 *
 * @param message The text message
 */
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message) {
    if (this.messageHandler != null) {
        this.messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
    }
}

/**
 * register message handler
 *
 * @param message
 */
public void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler) {
    this.messageHandler = msgHandler;
}

/**
 * Send a message.
 *
 * @param user
 * @param message
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
}

/**
 * Message handler.
 *
 * @author Jiji_Sasidharan
 */
public static interface MessageHandler {

    public void handleMessage(String message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to read how annotations works to understand this.The `@OnOpen` is an annotation. `@OnOpen` allows us to intercept the creation of a new session.

The Annotation Type [OnOpen](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/OnOpen.html)

> @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
>   @Target(value=METHOD)
>   public @interface OnOpen
>
> This method level annotation can be used to decorate a Java method
>   that wishes to be called when a new web socket session is open.
>
> The method may only take the following parameters:-
>
> optional Session parameter
>     optional EndpointConfig parameter
>     Zero to n String parameters annotated with the PathParam annotation.
>
> The parameters may appear in any order.

Answer (score 0):

When your `WebsocketClientEndpoint`'s constructor is called, it will try to open a connection to the websocket server which is located at `endPointURI` and by writing `@clientEndPoint` annotation you are extending the `EndPoint` class. So all the annotations like `@OnOpen`, `@OnMessage`, `OnClose` will be called depending on the signal received from the server. So when the connection is opened automatically the function which annotated with `@OnOpen` will be called.